# Data Import from .TXT to MS Access 2003

Tags: ms-access

I have a .txt file which contains data of a Access table.
Now I am using the Import utility of MS Access 2003 to import the data from the text file to a table. Theere is one data in the text file which has a space at the left.therefore the data looks like this :: [ 12461].
Now when the import is completed the data in the table looks like this :: [12461]. The left space is trimmed.
As a result my data is getting changed.
Any help?

Comment: Could you paste the exact line?

Comment: Col1: '00234' ; Col2: '  12461' . Inserting this in Access table generates  Col1: '00234' ; Col2: '12461'

Comment: Please copy and paste it from your txt into the question enclosed in backticks (formatting) and add your table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Both leading and trailing spaces will be trimmed when you import .txt data into Access. It is the case if you specify the column data type as either Text or Number. I would suggest the following workaround which depends on how much data your have. So:

1. Replace all spaces in your original .txt file with e.g. "^^^". It
   should be character(s) you know do not exist in your file.
2. Do your regular import. Please note altered columns will be
   automatically typed as Text.
3. Do Ctrl+H to replace all "^^^" with whitespace. This will fix leading spaces only, though.